# WLAN stopped working on my laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, laptop-repair

Since a couple of weeks now, my wlan has stopped working. Everything seems like before, it just doesn't find any networks anymore. Im now fairly sure that this is a hardware problem, because I didnt change anything, i just bootet up and it didnt work. Also i reinstalled my system a couple of times since now (Win 7, Win 8 and Archlinux) and every System recognized the Wlan card without a problem, but no Networks.

My Question is now: Where exactly is the problem? obviously i want to fix it, and im not sure what to do. I could buy a new WLan card and try it, but it could be, that the card is working and the antenna has some sort of Problem. Can i even fix that if its the antenna? It runs  AFAIK around the Laptop screen for best reception. The laptop is some sort of noname Laptop, with a noname standard-case, so it *could* be exchangeable

The weird thing: sometimes (maybe 1 out of 50 boots) the wlan works for ~10 minutes. I noticed that the WLAN-LED indicator is still correct (mostly off, except for those short periods when the Wlan is actually working)

Did anyone experience this sort of problem? any advice?

Comment: did you end up solving this problem else we might as well close it

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a WLAN hardware switch that might be in the off (red) position?

Comment: Well yes, i have one, but this was the first thing i tried. The switch works though, because when the wlan works (those mentioned few times) i can shut it down with the switch.